# Save me from Sierra

Tags: macos, mac-mini, downgrade

My Mac mini came with Sierra, out of the box. I want to run Pro Tools 10 HD as I already own a full license. Is there **any way** to downgrade it? I really want to run Mavericks. But it won't boot to my bootable Mavericks thumb drive. Erasing it just leads to internet recovery, which leads right back to Sierra.

Comment: You can downgrade your [Macmini7,1](http://www.everymac.com/systems/apple/mac_mini/specs/mac-mini-core-i7-3.0-late-2014-specs.html) to 10.10 but that's the end of the road...

Comment: Are you sure I can get to Yosemite, as it came out of the box with Sierra??? I've had success with a macbook pro that upgraded to Sierra but, I was informed by a Mac Certified Tech if it come out the box with Sierra, it would not. What if i replaced the SSD???

Comment: Perhaps you can [update to Pro Tools 12](https://shop.avid.com/ccrz__ProductDetails?viewState=DetailView&cartID=&sku=DYNA20008&&store=shop) at a price you can afford?

Comment: My advice is to buy a used one off ebay.

Answer (score 5):

The rule of thumb is - no Mac can boot to any OS that is older than itself.

This rule has some slight variance at the cusp of new OS/new Mac model, but can normally be relied on.
That would mean that a 2014 Mac Mini ought to be able to run anything from 10.10 onwards, but nothing earlier, e.g. Mavericks

Comment: But, can I beat that with a new ssd? Oh, and it's attempting internet recovery now. I'll take anything but sierra, as it won't even boot to an imaged hdd.

Comment: It would be interesting to learn what OS you actually get from Internet Recovery, 10.10 or 10.12. The usual idea is that you get "The OS it shipped with" but that model has remained the same for so long that it didn't ship with the same OS as the same model 3 years ago.